# How do i add 'alt' and 'title' attribute of <img> tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; }
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
var div = document.getElementById(pID);
var imgtag = "";
var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
var summ = summary_noimg;
if(img.length>=1) { 
imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
summ = summary_img;}
var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
div.innerHTML = summary;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

**How do i add  'alt' and 'title' attribute of img tag in javascript?**

***Ps: This is Blogger "Auto Read more with thumbnail" plugin.***

Comment: I don't recommend using both. Assistve tech sometimes will read both. Depending on the quality of the alt, this would be very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
for(var i in imgs){
   imgs[i].alt = ?
   imgs[i].title = ?
}
```

***or***

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
for(var i in imgs){
   imgs[i].setAttribute('alt', ?)
   imgs[i].setAttribute('title', ?)
}
```